# Is Western nuclear energy policy backfiring?

Tags: russian-federation, western-world, nuclear-energy

Official nuclear energy policy in the Western countries with little investments and continuously changing requirements has, with time, pushed into bankruptcy most of the major actors. The only left suppliers are [GE Hitachi Nuclear Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GE_Hitachi_Nuclear_Energy), which is on the verge of bankruptcy and has been in this status for quite some time, and [Areva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Areva) which produces the bloated and expensive [EPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPR_(nuclear_reactor)). There are some smaller actors, but they are eternally locked in the study phase, they have no commercial scale proposals.

As a result the Russian state company [Rosatom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosatom) has become the world's major supplier of services and plants with many [currently under construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosatom#Abroad). Trouble is that this is power, but not just electrical power, it is also political power, this situation gives Russia a lot of leverage in addition to the more publicised leverage they get from gas supplies. Moreover, they have this leverage also in a few NATO countries and it keeps growing since Hungary recently approved the extension of [their only nuclear power plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paks_Nuclear_Power_Plant). It is difficult to blame Hungary since they had little choice, but it means that the Russians will have under direct control for decades almost half of the electricity supplied to Hungary in addition to oil and gas supplies.

Adding to the loss of political leverage there is even the loss of the ability to influence future technologies. While [generation IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_IV_reactor) reactors are becoming like nuclear fusion, the eternal promise that will never be fulfilled the world is stuck with the PWR technology that produces a lot of nuclear waste. So even from this point of view the overall impact seems negative.

Did the Western world choose a nuclear energy policy that totally backfired or am I only seeing the negative aspects of the situation?

Comment: This is an opinion-based question.

Comment: Western nuclear "policy" has been a mess for the last 4 decades so that an easy yes.  Not sure it is policy in the sense of being government/top-driven, as much as grassroots/Greens-driven. Also not sure the Russians are the prime gainers, China seems to be:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_power_in_China Which is reassuring, given Russia's engineering *execution* skills.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica That is not correct, China has bought many different types of power plants from suppliers from all over the world. Now they are slowly developing their on technology, but they are still behind. For the moment they are aping elements that were developed 30 years ago and mixing them with the modern technology that is publicly available.

Comment: aping?  https://www.powermag.com/china-starts-up-first-fourth-generation-nuclear-reactor/  https://www.scmp.com/news/china/science/article/3160448/china-powers-fourth-generation-nuclear-reactor-steady-zero  Make no mistake, Russia can't manufacture itself out of a wet paper bag these days, so any long term technology challenges are more likely to come from China.  Besides, aping is a relative term w nuclear plants - the field seem stuck in the 70s, using outdated and dangerous designs - apparently coopted from military subs - rather than incremental improvements as most other engineering areas

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica What is sure is that Russia is building a lot of plants that will guarantee them some political leverage for decades. If then that political leverage passes to China it might create even more problems for the Western countries.

Comment: Ehh, not going to VTC this, but what kind of answer do you see here? (1) bad if they actually plan to compete on this market or use much nuclear power themselves (2) indifferent if their (pipe?) dream of relying only on renewables pans out. Is there anything else to say?

Comment: Nuclear power sounds great but we still haven't figured out how to deal with all the highly toxic waste that the plants produce. Sure they don't pollute the environment directly but the waste the produce does cause a lot of problems.

Comment: @Fizz "but what kind of answer do you see here?" As I see rather than a problem of using more nuclear power it was a problem of managing better the existing plants and do more research and development. Nuclear power in the Western countries has been caught between a rock and a hard place, opposition from one side mismanagement from the other side.

Comment: I have tried to make the question more answerable by changing its title. I still think the post is too long and that it actually includes what should be a part of the answer, but I also think it deserved to be reopened.

Comment: "Nuclear policy" usually refers to policy on nuclear weapons. Might be sensible to clarify it to "nuclear energy policy"

Comment: @user253751 good point. I edited the question.

Comment: also it's a nitpick but "nuclear" doesn't get a capital letter (unless it's at the start of a sentence or part of a proper noun, just like other words)

Comment: Seems like this could be more of an issue about the viability of nuclear energy, vs a particularly "western" or political issue.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet *"Seems like this could be more of an issue about the viability of nuclear energy,"* Not really. The world is using nuclear energy anyway, regardless of what public opinion in the Western country think about it. Even if it is phased out in the Western countries the rest of the world is building hundreds of reactor. Now when the matters come to the questions: what kind of nuclear technology? How do we use nuclear energy? The West is loosing the power to influence those matters and the result will be the extensive use of PWR that produce a lot of waste.

Comment: Where I live nuclear power was seen as a bridge technology and now as a dead end. Consequently it wasn't followed up anymore. Will it be used in the rest of the world? Not sure. New nuclear power plants become more and more expensive (see for example Hinkley Point C) to build and maintain. With all costs included it might simply be too expensive.

Comment: I seriously doubt their was such a thing as an "official nuclear energy policy in the Western countries". I think policies varied a lot among countries. Germany and Belgium decided to stop all nuclear energy production, the USA made tentative moves to re-start its dormant nuclear programs, France kept subsiding its own industry, also setting goals to reduce its dependency to nuclear - and then postponing them, Japan, well, had some issues (causing much of the "continuously changing requirements" in the last decade), etc.

Comment: @Trilarion You are confirming what I say. Hinkley point is an example of the bloated EPR and the only type of Western approach still in development. A cost between 15 and 20 Billion Euros for a single reactor cannot be justified without a massive corruption scheme. BTW the cost of the reactor core is only a small part of the total cost, most of it is due to the concrete infrastructure. Furthermore your assumption that nuclear is too expensive and has no future represent what is happening in Western countries. Definitely this is not what is happening in China, India and Russia and others.

Comment: @Evargalo You are right, there is not a single Western policy, but there are a lot of common elements. 1) Always changing requirements is one of them. 2) Little investment in experimental intermediate plans and jumping to giant production plants that turn out to be too dangerous is another common point. See how France went from phénix to superphénix. 3) Little investment on decent waste storage sites, little effort to reutilise the waste (I mean insufficient use or reprocessing and Mox fuels due to US political pressure). 4) Overreliance on PWR. ... continues

Comment: @Evargalo 5) Efforts to unite the forces to share research and developement costs ended up in farcical projects where some members instead of collaborating work to add confusion. 6) Corruption and cost inflation.

Comment: Lots of discussion, no answer. Must be a difficult question then. :)